# Google Maps iFrame Mobile View getting clipped

Tags: iphone, google-maps, iframe, mobile-safari

My client has a wordpress site and one page is embedding a map via `iframe`:

```
<iframe 
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=16162+Beach+Boulevard+%23100,+Huntington+Beach&amp;hl=en&amp;pcsi=2051297199499108728,1&amp;geocode=FUCmAgIdBaP3-A&amp;sll=33.728064,-117.988603&amp;sspn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;view=map&amp;cid=2051297199499108728&amp;hq=16162+Beach+Boulevard+%23100,+Huntington+Beach&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=33.730729,-117.987242&amp;spn=0.005354,0.006437&amp;z=16&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed" 
    height="350" 
    width="690" 
    frameborder="0" 
    marginwidth="0" 
    marginheight="0" 
    scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

When I view the page in my iPhone, it renders mobile-friendly and resizes the `iframe` to fit the viewport, but the state and zip code are getting cut off. I tried adjusting the height of the `iframe` and also the bottom padding, but it seems to be something on Google's end. Any idea how to fix this? I added a blue border to my `iframe` so you can see that it's not the `iframe` which is clipping the text:

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: can you post the live link?

Comment: Any luck solving this problem? Btw, the bounty already expired.

Comment: No luck :/ Waste of 50 rep

Comment: @Maverick, did you try my solution? Does my link look similar to your problem? Did you try any other solutions? Can you post a link? Edit: Btw, your 50 rep wouldn't have been wasted if you would have been more responsive to answers and comments. We are genuinely trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend posting a link to the site or posting some of the CSS. This would make it easier for the SO community to troubleshoot the issue.

I replicated your issue by removing the `iframe` attribute `width="690"`. I suspect the Wordpress CSS or some JavaScript is overriding the `iframe` width and cramming everything into the iPhone screen width.

To override the automatic resizing I just gave the `iframe` an `id` and set the width explicitly in my CSS.

```
#WidthTest {
    width:690px;
}
```

Regardless, I'm sure you can find a similar solution by digging around the Wordpress CSS/JavaScript.

Comment: I see it no longer hides the wrapped text but it bleeds off the edge of the phone screen with the width override.

Comment: @Maverick, check the site again. It's clear the solution works based on your reply. You just need to set the appropriate width so no bleeding occurs. Setting the width will prevent the issue you report in your question.

Answer (score -1):

I edited the code. This works great for me! You might want to change the width according to your needs.

```
<iframe width="380" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=16162+Beach+Boulevard+%23100,+Huntington+Beach&amp;hl=en&amp;pcsi=2051297199499108728,1&amp;geocode=FUCmAgIdBaP3-A&amp;sll=33.728064,-117.988603&amp;sspn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;view=map&amp;cid=2051297199499108728&amp;hq=16162+Beach+Boulevard+%23100,+Huntington+Beach&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=33.730729,-117.987242&amp;spn=0.005354,0.006437&amp;z=16&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```